# select column name in mysql table

Tags: mysql

hi i have a table named as 'target_hours'. targets and given levels-
 field names (L1,L2,L3,L4,L5) have be allocated and mentioned in the table in hours as follows.

```
|L1 | L2  | L3 | L4 | L5  |
|---| --- | ---|--- |---  |
|192| 168 | 144| 120| 96  |
```

i just need to get the level (filed name) of specific work that has been completed in  specific hours by using a `mysql query` by following below conditions. As a example lets take X hours.

```
L5 -->  L5 >= x hours 
L4 -->  L4 >= x hours > L5 
L3 -->  L3 >= x hours > L4 
L2 -->  L2 >= x hours > L3  
L1 -->  L1 >= x hours > L2
```

As a example if the specific task completed in 135 hours, the query should output as L3.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design.

Answer (score 0):

While I do agree with this being a symptom of a poor design, one way to solve this would be a bunch of unions:

```
select
  lvl
from (
  select l1 as lvl from limits
  union all
  select l2 from limits
  union all
  select l3 from limits
  union all
  select l4 from limits
  union all
  select l5 from limits
  order by
    lvl asc
) x
where
  lvl > 135
limit 
  0, 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be a normalisation of your table structure by moving the various levels into rows from columns:

```
level, hours
L1   , 192
L2   , 168
...
```

In this case the query would be:

```
select * from target_hours where hours>...
order by hours asc limit 1
```

The advantage of this solution is that it is flexible (you can have as many levels as you want) and the query can make use of indexes.

If you insists on maintaining your current table structure, then you can use the [case expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) to achieve the expected outcome:

```
select case
           when L5>=... then L5
           when L4>=... and ...>L5 then L4              
           when L3>=... and ...>L4 then L3
           when L2>=... and ...>L3 then L2
           when L1>=... and ...>L2 then L1
       end as hours
from target_hours
```

This solution is inflexible because if you have to check more levels, then you have to alter both the table structure and the query. Also, it cannot use indexes to find the relevant value.